# allow user and nonlogin guest to make posts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to allow the user and nonlogin visitors to create posts, but have trouble in coding
In ruby on rails tutorial, I find:
`@post =current_user.posts.build(params[:post])`
But the curren_user would be nil. 
Another approach is 
`@post.user = current_user`
This seems ok
but is this line too ugly? should I need to create a guest user to put those posts into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, assuming you are using devise:

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_current_user

  def set_current_user
    #create a new use if there is no logged in user
    #or you could probably load a default user
    current_user = User.new unless user_signed_in?  
  end 
end
```

Comment: What does the 'User.new' mean? If I implement `@post =current_user.posts.build(params[:post])` would this help? and what would be stored into the database as the writer?

Comment: What I'm doing here is, making the current_user available for all the time, irrespective of user logged or not. Because of that your current_user variable will not be nil. So you could use any method on top of it

Answer (score 0):

```
@post =current_user.posts.build(params[:post], :user_id => current_user.id)
```

Use like that

Comment: But what happens if `current_user` is `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a number of ways. The key is to have a user that the posts can be associated with. To do that you could start of with a user model that has a `guest:boolean` column in the database and work of that for non authenticated users. You would then set `session[:user_id]` to the id of a newly created user with guest set to true and have the `current_user()` method in the application controller give you a `User` object based on `session[:user_id]`. Normal users would work the same, but would have the guest column set to false of cause.

If you have more complicated needs for your guests you could look in to using single table inheritance (STI) and have a `User` base model that you subclass to `Guest` and `Member`. The User model would hold the shared logic and the subclasses would hold their specialized logic but they would all share one table in the database.

Ryan Bates over at RailsCasts.com has two screencasts on exactly this. Go check them out: [393 - Guest user record](http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record)(free) and [394 - STI and Polymorphic Associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations)(pro). They go through in detail exactly how to do this and talk a lot about the pros and cons of each approach too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use user role system into the project using a combination of Devise and CanCan.

Suppose you have two roles: **guest and general_user.**

Then define in User model-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  // Devise stuff comes here..

  //this is roles definition
  ROLES = %w[general_user guest]

  def role?(role)
    roles.include? role.to_s
  end
end
```

**role.rb**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :users, :through => :posts
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**ability.rb (this is for CanCan)**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new #guest user

    if user.role? :general_user
      can :create, :all
      can :manage, :all
      can :read, :all
    end

   if user.role?(:guest)
    can :create, Post
    can :update, Post do |post|
      post.try(:user) == user
    end

   end   
  end
```

**posts/index.html.erb**

```
<% if can? :create, Post%>
  <p><%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path %></p>
<% end %>
```

Then for guests users -

```
user.posts.build(params[:post], :user_id => 0)
```

where `user` is initialized using cancan `ability` class and `user_id` value can be anything fixed that you assign for any guest. In this example, I supposed `:user_id => 0`, then its a guest entry post.

and for logged in users -

```
current_user.posts.build(params[:post], :user_id => current_user.id)
```

where `current_user` is `devise` logged in user.

For more check: [Cancan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).