# Non-login users for devise

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using devise on Rails 4.0. I need non-login users, that is, people who are considered part of a team but never need to log in or interact with the app, they just get emails, appear in different lists and so on (in the future, however, they can potentially become users).

Ways I'm guessing how to do it are to:

- programmatically add them, then -
- possibly generate the devise views so I can alter them for non-login users?
- write the controller to block non-login users?

I need to know what would be the basic steps for implementing non-login users.

Comment: Instead of rewriting the steps here, see if you can borrow from the following answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557448/allow-user-and-nonlogin-guest-to-make-posts-in-rails

Comment: @KirtiThorat Thanks. There are good pointers there, which I did not find before. I'll look into it. Blessings.

Comment: I was also looking for the same issue. In my case, I have one type of users who login to the system. Now I need to have another type of users who doesn't need to login. This type of users will not have any email, passsword fields, just name will be enough. Do you have any idea, how can we achieve this ?